# Safely destroying and re-creating a singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c

In an Objective-C game for iOS, I have a few objects as singletons. A World object, Scoreboard object for example.

```
+ (World *)sharedWorld {
    if (sharedWorld == nil) {
        sharedWorld = [[World alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedWorld;
}
```

However, I'm realizing that if a user backs out to a main menu, and clicks "new game" again, it's obviously not re-instantiating because these are singletons.

I need a safe way to destroy these (i.e. setting them to nil) so that I can cleanly create new instances. However, even with just a simple test of setting the objects to nil when the user goes back to the main menu, the next time they're instantiated I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors.

Comment: You can't destroy things completely with ARC. Setting them to nil will eventually dealloc them.

Comment: Not sure why you would create a run once instance of a class and try to destroy it. Would suggest your approach and pattern is wrong. A singleton usually contains values and methods that you want to maintain through the app's lifecycle. Trying to destroy this pattern doesn't make sense. Why are these classes singletons? What's in them?

Comment: I had never intended to destroy them but hadn't fully thought it through. I had thought that I only needed one instance but I've now realized that if a user doesn't quit the application and starts a new game, I really do need a new instance. I'll probably just try to make them properties of a game class rather than have them all be singletons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a singleton should never be destroyed (otherwise it wouldn't be called a singleton!). Try to use a different pattern, e.g. making it a property of a singleton object, like this

```
@interface App

@property (strong, nonatomic) World *world;

@end
```

and set it to `nil`, when you want to destroy it. Or simply make sure all the objects in that `world` has reference to the `world` they live in.

If you really need to nilify a singleton (you have a good justification, or it simply for convenience), then try this

```
static World *g_world;

@implementation World

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    if (!g_world) {
        g_world = [[World alloc] init];
    }

    return g_world;
}

+ (void)deallocateSharedInstance {
    g_world = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: The dispatch_once(…) calls mean that effectively you can create the singleton once and you can destroy it once. If you want to be able to reset a singleton you cannot use dispatch_once.

Comment: Having thought through the fact that I really shouldn't use singletons, I completely agree with this and will implement it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create one class method to reset your Singleton object.
I am using in my project Like

```
World *sharedInstance = nil;
+ (World *)sharedWorld {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[World alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

// call this method when you want to reset shared object
+(void)reset
{
    sharedInstance = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to dig more and nullify more objects, that are dependent.
If you try simple example on new project, that will not be reproduced, I assume. This is because your current project structure is much more complicated, than simple case. Onl reason for this I see - is nullifying few more  dependent objects as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not completely release your singleton instance (sharedWorld = nil), instead you should release the resources resides inside the singleton (sharedWorld.resourceA = nil), for that you can create a function called `releaseResources` and set every resource to nil in this method.